# There's a lot (of biscuits). How can it be explained from the grammatical point of view?

Tags: singular-vs-plural, predicate

While flicking through a textbook for beginners I came across the following:

> How many biscuits are there? - There's a lot!

I wonder how "there is" can be explained to a student who knows that "biscuits" is a countable noun given in the plural in the sentence.

Comment: Biscuits are something that *can* be counted, yes.  However, it is usually more important to know if there are enough biscuits for everyone, or if there are too few to share.  "There are a few biscuits left if you want to get one before they're gone" is more useful than "There are four and a half biscuits in the breakroom".  Therefore, "a lot" of biscuits is a normal way to provide a count.  As "a lot" is singular, it is grammatical to use "there is" here.

Comment: @MikeKozar If we assume that *of biscuits* was omitted, *a lot* needs a verb in the plural: *There **are** a lot of biscuits.* The duplicate answers the question of why *is* was used instead.